# Decoding Traceback message

Tags: python

As part of Hackerrank's Python practice code, I was trying out the the [Mutation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-mutations/problem) problem where the task is quoted below.

> Read a given string, change the character at a given index and then print the modified string.

This is the code that I've come up with:

```
string = 'audiophile'
character = 'u'
position = 5

def mutate_string(string, position, character):
    string = string[:int(position)] + {} + string[int(position)+1:].format(character)
    return string

mutate_string(string, position, character)
```

It raises a `TypeError: must be str, not dict` and here's the whole `Traceback` message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mutations.py", line 13, in <module>
    mutate_string(string, position, character)
  File "mutations.py", line 6, in mutate_string
    string = string[:int(position)] + {} + string[int(position)+1:].format(str(character))
TypeError: must be str, not dict
```

I'm trying to decode and understand the `Traceback` message so that I could move on with the code. Also it would be wonderful if I could get some suggestions on the approach I've taken writing the code.

Comment: `+ {} +`. `{}` is not a string, it's a dict. Hence you can't append it to a string. What you might be looking for, is `+ '{}' +`? And even `+ '{}.format(...)`?

Comment: In python 3.6+ you can also use    f'somestring {variablename}' and it does the same thing as 'somestring {}'.format(variablename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but your sintax is wrong

Here how it should be:

```
string = 'audiophile'
character = 'u'
position = 5

def mutate_string(string, position, character):
    string = string[:int(position)] + '{}'.format(character) + string[int(position)+1:]
    return string

mutate_string(string, position, character)
```

`format()` is a `String()` class function, that is why your code din't work

I hope it helped

Comment: Oh I see! That was a very trivial mistake but yeah it helped a lot to understand what was going on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much more readable and understandable to use the format method like that:

```
string = 'audiophile'
character = 'u'
position = 5


def mutate_string(string, position, character):
    string = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(string[:position], character, string[position+1:])
    return string


mutate_string(string, position, character)
```

The traceback itself was caused by the {} in your concatenation. It was not inside brackets so it was interpreted as an empty dict. As soon as you tried to add that to your substrings the Python interpreter bailed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I never thought about writing it that way but now I know. I learnt something new today that's for sure.